# omitempty doesn't omit interface nil values in JSON

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to omit nil interface values

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyStruct struct{
 Val interface{} `json:"val,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var s []string
    s = nil
    m := MyStruct{
    Val : s,
    }

    b, _:=  json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Here is the playground link https://play.golang.org/p/cAE1IrSPgm
This outputs

```
{"val":null}
```

Why is it not treating it as an empty value? Is there a way to omit these nil values from json.

Comment: `m.Val` in this example is not nil.

Comment: A *variable pointing to `nil`* is not the same with *variable pointing to a variable having `nil` value*. As pointed by Cerise Limon, the later is not `nil`, i.e. `m.Val` pointing to a variable `s`. It will be omitted if you define `m` as `m := MyStruct{ Val: nil }`.

Comment: @putu I understand. But in my case values to variable s comes from a database query and s needs to be assigned to Val. So there's no way it could be a direct assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object unless
>
> - the field's tag is "-", or
> - the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option.
>
> The empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.

The reason it is not omitting is stated [here](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error)

> An interface value is nil only if the inner value and type are both
> unset, (nil, nil). In particular, a nil interface will always hold a
> nil type. If we store a nil pointer of type *int inside an interface
> value, the inner type will be *int regardless of the value of the
> pointer: (*int, nil). Such an interface value will therefore be
> non-nil even when the pointer inside is nil.

[eg](https://play.golang.org/p/q297qL5vjF):

```
var s []string
s = nil
var temp interface{}
fmt.Println(temp==nil) // true
temp = s
fmt.Println(temp==nil) // false
```

For your case, you can do

https://play.golang.org/p/ZZ_Vzwq4QF
or
https://play.golang.org/p/S5lMgqVXuB

Comment: This is not exactly the same case I'm talking. You've directly assigned nil to Val

Comment: Ah I see your question now, let me change the answer.